# remove custom tools in visual studio for mac 2022 or specFlow designer codebehind generation is not compatible with MSBuild codebehind generation

Tags: visual-studio-mac, xamarin.uitest

I am getting this error while building my test project.
I have latest stable 3.9.74 version of specflow and its required packages.

Error : "specFlow designer codebehind generation is not compatible with MSBuild codebehind generation."

when i explored on this people says remove custom tools but i am not able to do it.
Could anyone please help me with how to remove custom tools in visual studio for mac 2022?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zydRe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer,

edit your .csproj file and remove SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator
manually